# Build Error when building blank Grails Project in GGTS

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I have freshly downloaded GGTS 3.5.1 and pointed it to grails-2.4.0 and jdk_1.8.0_05 but I can't build just a blank grails project without getting build errors.

The exact error is.

```
Building Workspace

Errors Occurred During The Build
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'test'.
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Number;
```

I have tried booting using the -clean flag, downloading other versions of groovy, grails and jdk. This error even occurs exactly the same on my desktop and laptop, so I guess something I'm doing in the setup has to be wrong.

Comment: what happens if you just unzip GGTS 3.5.1 and run it, try creating a project under default config. Does this work?

Comment: Thanks, Vahid I actually did go back and look at the site to download just the zip of the ggts and saw there was a 3.6 out so I downloaded that and it seems to be working. Im thinking I may have had a 32 bit version pointing to a 64bit java or something.

Answer (score 2):

What was the Groovy compiler specified for in your GGTS? I think for Grails 2.4 you'd need Groovy 2.3 compiler set in the preferences.

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly my problem (with fresh install of GGTS 3.5.1 64 bit on Fedora Linux 20 with JDK 1.8.0_5, installed Grails but didn't know to install also groovy 2.3)